# Angularjs not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I am working on web project where i am working on angular js to display images and if i click an image it will zoomed. I have created one sample application its working fine but when i started to create one sample application it gives warning for its internal tags.

My Html file where it gives warnings(for ng-app,ng-controller,ng-src,ng-repeat) ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- <script src="http://code.angular.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script> -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/underscore-min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/album.css"></script>

<title>Angular album</title>

</head>

<body>
jsp

<div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
<div id="albumImage">
<img ng-src="{{currentImage.image}}" alt="{{currentImage.description}}">

</div>

<div id = "thumbWrapper">
<ul id="thumbList">
<li ng-repeat ="image in images"  ng-click="setCurrentImage(image)">
<img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}" alt="{{image.description}}">

</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you add the Javascript at the bottom of the body?

Comment: @Matt which javascript are you talking about..

Comment: Sorry, I meant the script tags. I'm not too well versed with Angular but I know that with Backbone I've had problems when defining templates after adding the JS source files.

Comment: where's your AlbumCtrl code?

Comment: post your controllers code and main angular module, post the warnings

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your problem is here:

```
<div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
```

I don't see where this controller is defined. It's possible you got your file extension wrong, and that's why:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/album.css"></script>
<!-- I would have expected to see .js, not .css, in the path above -->
```